# Command terminated right after vector input

Tags: c++, vector

I created this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> m(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>m[i];
    }
    
    sort(m.begin(),m.end());

    vector<bool> used(n,false);
    for(int i=n;i>0;i--){
        for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
            if((m[i]/m[j]>=2)&&(used[i]==false))
                used[j]=true;
        }
    }

    int numOfElem=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(used[i]!=true){
            numOfElem++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<numOfElem<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Now for some reason right after I input elements of vector m I get command terminated, does anyone know the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the vectors `m` and `used` out of bounds since you start iterating with `i == n` (the size of the vectors). This causes your program to have *undefined behavior* and a crash is one possible outcome of that.

Suggested fix:

```
for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // start with n-1 and ...
    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--) { // ... include 0 in the loop
```

Also note that `m[i] / m[j]` may be a *division by zero* and throw an exception, so you may want to check if `m[j] == 0` before doing the division too.